# How to lock file without checking out in perforce

Tags: perforce

So I have some resource files I use for unit testing that I don't want changed (otherwise the unit tests will break).

Is there a way to lock these files using p4v **without** checking out the file?

I do not have admin rights btw.

Comment: You'll increase your chances of getting an answer if you approach this with an open mind, explaining the problem and the constraints.  In particular, why do you feel you need to use locking as compared to some other approach?

Comment: When you say that you don't want the file changed, do you mean in your workspace? Or in the depot?

Comment: @user1054341 I'm saying I don't want to file changed in the depot. Everyone uses the same unit test project in my group, so if someone accidentally changes it, the tests will most likely break.

Comment: I still don't understand the requirement here.  One of the main things about putting files in version control is that you can get the previous versions back easily, so what's the big deal if somebody accidentally changes a file ?  You can just roll back to a previous version.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to check the files out, it's pretty easy to solve. Just open the files for edit, and then lock them. As long as you keep them open and locked, they should be safe - though I believe an admin could forcibly unlock them.

You can always create a second workspace for locking them if you don't want to clutter up your main one.

Comment: I ended up checking the files out and locking them that way. I really wish there was a way to lock files without checking them out though. I suppose in the end it really doesn't matter (except that it adds clutter to my checkin list)

Comment: To reduce clutter you can move the offending files to a separate pending changelist.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that could work *without* needing to check the file out / locking it.

1. Using P4 Permissions you can assign **read** access to the files or directory in the depot. Everyone will still be able read the files, which is essential for their work, however no-one without the correct permissions will be allowed to submit. Read more about the [p4 protect command in manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/protect.html).
2. Write a P4 Trigger that checks for the files the files on pre-submit, if found reject the changelist. Read more about the [p4 triggers command in the manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/triggers.html).

To do both of these, you will need help from your friendly superuser/administrator. Option 1 is by far the best solution as triggers can slow your server down if you have too many or them doing too much. It will up-to you administrator if they want to add the permission to the protect table.

**Note:** Permissions/Protect as synonymous, like Workspace/Client.